# MVC and Property Terminology in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, terminology

I am having a problem with terminology I think. Is a `ViewController` the Controller portion of MVC? Or is it not the same thing. Is this combining the VC of MVC into one file?

Properties like `.backgroundColor` and `.size` are these the same thing as the `@property` and `@synthesize` and if so is this the same thing as an attribute? Meaning can properties and attributes be interchangeable terms in Objective-C or are they different? For example does `.backgroundColor` have the `@properties` syntax in some Cocoa class or is this the wrong way to look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NSViewController` subclass is definitely the controller in MVC. It controls the view and pushes data from your model classes into it.

You are also correct about `.backgroundColor` and all other dot-notation properties on built-in Cocoa classes. They are defined with `@property` and `@synthesize` just like classes you would write. **However**, there are more simple classes (actually, they are structs) used within Cocoa (such as `NSSize` and `NSRange`). When you access those fields with dot-notation (such as `range.length`, assuming `range` is an `NSRange`), they are not using `@property` or `@synthesize` since they are not actually Objective-C classes at all, but simple C structs.

I personally use "attribute" and "property" simultaneously in Objective-C, although other developers may disagree.

Comment: Thanks Marc this terminology sometimes gets me doubting myself. I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! Since this answer helped you, you can mark it as the "accepted" answer by clicking the green checkmark. That way other people will know you found it helpful. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. An Objective-C class with the name "ViewController" in it's name is an Apple convention which indicates that it is a part of the 'Controller' portion according to the [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) paradigm.

- Model:      Your data class.
- View:       `NSView`, `NSImageView`, etc.
- Controller: `NSViewController` class.

  .backgroundColor and .size are both properties.
- The `@property` keyword is the **declaration** keyword for a property.
- The `@synthesize` keyword is required to **instantiate** the property.

Comment: Thanks Brock nice way to look at it!